# Change routes array programmatically inside routing module

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have a routing module let's say `asset-monitoring.routing.ts` like this

```
    const mapRoutes: Routes = [
          { path: 'asset/:id', component: AssetPageComponent },
          { path: 'grid', component: GridMainComponent }
    ]

    @NgModule({
        imports: [RouterModule.forChild(mapRoutes)],
        exports: [RouterModule],
        providers: []
    })
    export class AssetMonitoringRoutingModule {}
```

and i want to change the `mapRoutes` array is some way(alter, add or delete a route) from inside the constructor of `AssetMonitoringRoutingModule` class depending on some data i get from some service.

Is this possible?

I tried to DI Router in the constructor and get the router config like this:

```
export class AssetMonitoringRoutingModule {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    console.log(this.router.config);
  }

}
```

But because my app is very large it is difficult to go to the specific routes array.

Is any other better approach?

Comment: would spiting this route array in many other ones help? you could make the routes lazy-loaded as the user navigates